# Using variables, arrays, and functions for accurate sum and average calculation

Tags: arrays, c, variables

im new to programing, but my code including an array, keeps giving 0 as the sum of the arrays. my code is:

```
/*y = (1 / (p * sqrt(2π))) * e^((-1/2) * ((a - x) / p)^2)
```

In this equation:

I tried solving it on a side(the sum and the average) but things didn't work out great for me.

```
/* 
a represents the grade or score achieved by a student.
y represents the probability density of obtaining that grade.
x represents the mean (average) grade.
p represents the standard deviation, which measures the spread or variability of the grades.*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float curve(int a, float p, float x);
int main()
{
    int i = 0, grade[100], sum = 0, n = 0, success = 0, fail = 0, low = 100, high = 0;
    float avg, sd;
    printf("ente the grade:\n");
    scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
    while (grade[i] != -1)
    { // grade[i] >=60? success++:fail++;
        // if (grade[i]>high)
        // high=grade[i];
        // if (grade[i]<low)
        // low=grade[i];
        n++;
        i++;
        sum = sum + (grade[i]);
        printf("ente the grade:\n");
        scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n", grade[i] + 10);
    }
    avg = sum / n;
    // sd=pow(garde)
    printf("the sum of the class is %d\n", sum);
    printf("the average of the class is %f\n", avg);
    printf("the number of the student who passed the exam is %d\n", success);
    printf("the number of the student who failed the exam is %d\n", fail);
    printf("the highest mark in the class is %d\n", high);
    printf("the lowest mark in the class is %d\n", low);
    if (avg < 50)
    {
        printf("raise suggested\n");
        printf("the new average of the class is %f\n", (avg + 10));
    }
    else if (avg > 50 && avg < 60)
    {
        printf("curve suggested\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
float curve(int a, float p, float x)
{
    float y;
    y = (1 / (p * sqrt(2 * (3.14159)))) * pow((2.718), ((-1 / 2) * ((a - x) / p) * ((a - x) / p)));
    return y;
}
```

Comment: (Odd, I can't comment on this question without adding some boilerplate - it says it's because I downvoted it, but I did not) Anyway: `(-1 / 2)` results in `0` because it's an integer division. You probably want `(-1. / 2)`

Comment: You never call `curve()`, why is it relevant?

Comment: `sum = sum + (grade[i]);` needs to be *before* `i++`. You're adding the next element to `sum`, not the element the user just entered.

Comment: Aside: you have a terrible approximation for *e*. That and *π* are probably defined in the `math.h` library. Also, please use `double` unless there is a very good reason why you must use `float`.

Comment: @WeatherVane `math.h` is *not* a library.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, there are issues with reading input. You would be well-advised to use a do...while loop as you need to loop at least *once*.

```
int main(void) {
    int grades[100];
    int n = 0;

    do {
        scanf("%d", &grades[n++]);
    } while (n < 100 && grades[n-1] != -1);

    n--; // exclude the -1 value
}
```

You can now readily iterate over these values to find the sum and from that the average.

This should be error-checking the return value of `scanf` but that's another issue. Here `n` will record the number of grades input.

Keep in mind also that doing math on two integers will always yield an integer result, even if the value is then assigned to a `float` or `double` variable.

Comment: You *must* check the value returned by `scanf`.  Perhaps `while( n < 100 && 1 == scanf("%3d", grades + n) && grades[n++] != -1 ) { ... }`